# remove index.php and foldername with mod_rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

The URL Structure on my website is the following: `http://www.mydomain.tld/index.php/pages/sitename`. Now I want to remove the `index.php/pages`, to let the URL Structure be like `http://www.mydomain.tld/sitename`. Furthermore, I want to rename some `sitename`'s individual.

I already removed the index.php, thats no problem. So currently my .htacces-File looks like

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|(.*)\.swf|forums|images|css|downloads|jquery|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico|pam)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.tld\.de$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.tld/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But if I append `/pages` to the first RewriteCond or RewriteRule, it doesn't work.
Do you have some ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Have your .htaccess like this:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.tld\.de$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.tld/$1 [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^((?!index\.php/pages/).*)$ index.php/pages/$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for you help, but I think that doesn't work. I still get a 404 with www.mydomain.tld/sitename. And I cant use NE with the first RewriteRule. If I use it, I can't enter my Website through http://mydomain.tld.

Comment: What is the full URL you entered in browser and where is this .htaccess located?

Comment: This .htaccess is located directly in the root-folder of the domain. And I tried to call http://www.mydomain.tld/sitename, but this doesn't work. It's still http://www.mydomain.tld/pages/sitename

Comment: What do you mean by `It's still mydomain.tld/pages/sitename`? When you enter: `http://mydomain.tld/index.php/pages/sitename` does it load the correct page?

Comment: Yes, when I enter http://mydomain.tld/index.php/pages/sitename, it does load the correct page.